# Unknow css change border's color

Tags: css

Select checkbox auto changes border's color after open select checkbox.

I can't find any class change select checkbox color on Developer tool,how to solve the problem?

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBqUM.jpg)

Comment: That is not a “demo”, it’s an _image_. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: But this is likely not actually a border, but a _focus outline_. Go do some research using that keyword.

Comment: sorry about that....   because it is wordpress plug , I don't know which part code have problem , so I update image.

Comment: and thanks your help , It is actually focus outline.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When updated select element set as :focus. You can chande styles of focus state via css:

```css
.select:focus {
  outline: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<select class="select" name="" id="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="1">3</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="1">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks,It does work!